# jsf spring security user info

Tags: jsf, authentication, spring-security

I'm new at Spring Security. I'm using jsf2 with spring security 3. Three questions:

1. How can I access, from a session managed bean, the user info (name,password,roles) of the user currently logged in?

   In order to use it in a view, for example for rendering elements depending on the roles of the user.
2. How can I know if a user is logged in? In order to show in a view a "login link" if the user is not logged in, or a "logout link" if the user is logged in. Which property of Spring Security do I have to use in my managed bean to store this info and use it in the view?
3. The "login link" is just a GET request to the URL of the login page. But how can I show "logout link"? Do it have to be a POST request and use "h:commandLink" like this?:

   ```
   <h:commandLink value="Logout" action="#{request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_logout" />
   ```

   Or can it be a GET request?:

   ```
   <h:link value="Logout" outcome="#{request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_logout" />
   ```

Thank you very much in advanced.

Comment: Maybe this could provide some help - http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The object authentication is who save this properties, you can obtain with next line in your managedBean:

   `Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();`
2. A user is logged if his Authentication is not a instace of `AnonymousAuthenticationToken`, in your `spring-security-context.xml` you must define the urls intercepted by Spring.

   The first interceptor is not analyzed by Spring. In this case the Authentication object is an instance of `AnonymousAuthenticationToken`.

   The second interceptor is analyzed by Spring and the user is redirected to login page declared in `spring-security-context.xml`

   ```
   /* This is a example for to obtain the rol name for example for generate automatic menu */
   Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
   String namePrincipalRol = null;
   if (auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) {
       namePrincipalRol = "ROLE_ANONYMOUS";
   } else {
       namePrincipalRol = auth.getAuthorities().iterator().next().getAuthority();
   }
   ```
3. Good question, **I am not sure** but I think I remember having read that it must be POST, would be interesting to try. I use **h:outputLink**

Kind regards.

Comment: Thank you very much @Rafael for your answer. I forgot this question beacuse I asked it long time ago. I solved it on my own reading about the framework and testing. Finally in question (3) I also used h:outputLink (renders a html link <a> with href), it's a GET request, not a post. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome, thank you for the info. Although the question is old, the answer can be helpful in the future.